# getting wrong output while calculating maximum multiples of certain integer

Tags: java, arrays

We have array of size n  and their are two integers m and k. we can add any positive number to any element of the array such that the total value that we added doesn't exceed k.
so my question is how to find maximize the multiples of m in the resultant array.
let say we have n=5 , m=2,k=2 and arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5}. lets add 1 to arr[0] and add 1 to arr[2] the final array will be arr[]={2,2,4,4,5} now there are 4 elements which are multiples of m=2.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n =5;
        int m =4;
        int k =3;
        int count=0;
        
        int[] arr ={17,8,9,1,4};
    
        
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j =0;j<=k;j++){
                arr[i]=arr[i]+j;
                if(arr[i]%m==0){
                 count++;
                  
                }
            }
            
          
            
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

**Expected Output:- 3**

**My output:- 5**

Comment: In the example you gave you are adding 1 to only arr[0] and arr[2]. But in the code there's no condition for that, it's doing it in every step. I guess what you're missing and also what i didn't understand is : What is the condition for adding?

Comment: so in the example i have given only the condition that we can add (we will add digit it means lets say if we have a first array element 1 after adding 1 it will be 2 )any integer in the which is less than or equal to 2. so for each digit getting multiples for m are maximum.

Comment: So you're saying if the number already is multiple of the given m then there's no need to add. But again why didn't you add 1 to 5 in the example? Because it's not multiple of 2 but if you add 1, it will be.

Comment: There's several things wrong with your code. Nowhere you limit yourself with not exceeding `k`. And you just are adding 1,2,3 .. k to each number and checks the divisibility of that. That's nothing like what you want from the problem statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a completely different approach. Ask yourself, what you you need to add to a `number` to make it divisible by `m`? the answer to that it:

```
(m - number % m) % m
```

Apply this to every number of the array then sort those number from low to high. Then take away those numbers from `k` until it's negative then you know the answer. Putting it together you could do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m =4;
    int k =3;
    int count=0;

    int[] arr ={17,8,9,1,4};

    int[] result = Arrays.stream(arr).map(operand -> (m - operand % m) % m).sorted().toArray();

    for (int i : result) {
        if (k - i >= 0) {
            k = k - i;
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other approach because I'm not getting this part  `map(operand -> (m - operand % m) % m)`

Comment: @Rushi `map` turns one array into another by performing an operation on every element of it. The operation is defined by first giving the element some name, that's `operand` here, then `->` and then what you do with it. I could have named it different. like `map(i -> (m - i % m) % m)`. This would do the same. An easier example would be `map(i -> i + 1)`. This would turn `{1,2,3,4,5}` into `{2,3,4,5,6}`

Comment: Great. so Is it necessary to calculate these values `map(operand -> (m - operand % m) % m)`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I guess I understood the logic.

There's a couple of things you need to do in your code.

1. You need to check if the item is already multiple of `m`. If it is, inner `for` needs a `break`.
2. You need to do the same thing after adding `j` to the item.

   ```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n =5;
            int m =4;
            int k =3;
            int count=0;

            int[] arr ={17,8,9,1,4};


            for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j =0;j<=k;j++){
                    // check initial
                    if(arr[i]%m==0){
                     break;
                    }
                    // add
                    arr[i]=arr[i]+j;
                    // check again
                    if(arr[i]%m==0){
                     count++;
                     break;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Final Array : " + Arrays.toString(arr));
            System.out.println("Count : " + count);
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: but for this array {1,2,3,4,5} when we add 1 to arr[0] and 1 to arr[2] then count must be 4 but your output is 3

Comment: I'm sorry but, what?! You said in your OP the expected result is 3.

Comment: just take the input as n=5, k=2,m=2 and array is  {1,2,3,4,5} so we want maximum multiples. now run your code.